# Custom login with gmail button

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

I refer this link http://jeradbitner.com/angular-directive.g-signin/ for the login with gmail in my angular js Web application. but i want to change button style. If any other plugin available or other way for login with gmail please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: there is css for it? - https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin/blob/master/google-plus-signin.css

Comment: try your css but still it will take default google css so can't  we get out css effect.